# Quickest way to cycle through different column values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database table which is storing information on various projects. It looks something like this:

```
Project ID | Field  |  Truth Value
dog        |  1a    |   True
dog        |  1b    |   True
dog        |  1c    |   False
cat        |  1a    |   True
cat        |  1b    |   True
cat        |  1c    |   False
```

What I want to do is be able to cycle through these projects. I've had two ideas which I'm not sure are very efficient. The first idea is to use a filter as follows:

```
Columns("B:B").AutoFilter
Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1a", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

And then use the values remaining, or secondly to use the fact that each project has 3 fields and do something with just adding 3 to the row number used to grab the Projects Name.

In actual fact the project is more complicated as the Truth Values correspond to tick boxes on another page, so it's important to me to know if there's an easier way to do all of this.
 To put this into context the idea is that on said other page, one would be able to flick between the projects and both see/edit which boxes are ticked for each.

Comment: How big is this data set that you are cycling through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another possible answer, that's a bit more involved, but very fast. You can use ADODB to query your excel worksheet as if it were a database. This would be handy if you wanted to get a count of "TRUE" Truth Values for each distinct project, or some similarly databasicnessishnessicity. (that's a word, dangit).

```
Sub LoopDistinctProjects()

    'Variables
    Dim objConn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strFileName As String, strSQL As String, strConn As String
    Dim wsTable As Worksheet

    'Sheet with the data
    Set wsTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Make a new file with _tmp appended to it in same folder
    strFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    strFileName = Replace(strFileName, ".xls", "_tmp.xls")
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strFileName

    'Fancy ADODB stuff.. essentially open up that copy we just saves as if it were a database
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"""
    objConn.Open strConn

    'This is the sql string we will use to query the excel/database. The field names are the names in Row 1 of the sheet
    strSQL = "SELECT [Project] FROM [" & wsTable.Name & "$] WHERE [Project] IS NOT NULL GROUP BY [Project];"

    'Fancy ADODB stuff to apply that SQL statement to the excel/database
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open strSQL, objConn

    'move to the first record (it's already there... probably)
    rs.Movefirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs.Fields("Project").Value '<----That's a distinct project right there.
        rs.movenext
    Loop

    'close it up
    rs.Close
    objConn.Close

    'Remove that tmp workbook
    Kill strFileName

End Sub
```

High level, this makes a copy of your worksheet in the same folder, it then uses ADODB to open a database connection to the worksheet using the ACE OLEDB provider.

It then writes the simple query `SELECT [Project] FROM [" & wsTable.Name & "$] WHERE [Project] IS NOT NULL GROUP BY [Project];` This will bring back distinct project names from the worksheet that you set up near the top (assuming "Project" is the field name/column header.

It opens the recordset with that query and then loops through the results writing them to the immediates window in VBE (feel free to do whatever you would like here).

Then it closes the connection and deletes the sheet.

Like I said, this is a bit more involved, but if you need to do something fancier than just getting distinct, this is a solid route to explore.... and even if you are just getting distinct, it's not so bad if you don't mind the trade off of code overhead.

Comment: This looks very interesting. I'll mark this useful even though I won't yet use it. Have you got any good links to learn about ADODB? Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know anything off the top of my head, but ADODB is used everywhere so there is plenty of help on the internet. It's usually used to connect to databases to query them or run stored procedures and the like, but here it's used to turn Excel into a traditional RDBMS. If you make use of it, it will make you rethink using vlookups. I would suggest that you add the reference though: Tools>References then choose "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8". That way you'll have helper text as you write code. I used late binding in this example so no reference is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through, three at a time, you can use a for loop:

```
Sub test()
    Dim intRow as integer
    Dim strProject as string

    For intRow = 1 to 500 step 3  '1 is starting row, 500 is ending
        strProject = Sheet1.Range("B" & intRow).value
    Next intRow
End Sub
```

This seems like as good a way to do it as any. I'm not sure that your autofilter idea would work since it only hides the rows that are not included in the filter, so looping through rows will still get you everything. If there are sometimes more or less than three lines for each project you could loop through every row and test to make sure it's different:

```
Sub test()
    Dim intRow as integer
    Dim strProject as string

    For intRow = 1 to 500 '1 is starting row, 500 is ending
        if strProject <> Sheet1.Range("B" & intRow).value
            strProject = Sheet1.Range("B" & intRow).value
        End if
    Next intRow
End Sub
```

This will be slower since it has to loop through every row AND test it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I know how to do it with a loop, I didn't write out the code because I would have had to simplify what I've written so I chose to just describe it. The autofilter method would work also, because I would cycle through the range of visible rows. What I'm asking is if there is a more efficient or slick way to do this. And yes it always is the same amount of fields for each project, so it probably makes sense to use the "every x rows method".